# Screen Animation is not recording

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I uses `ScreenCaptureView`[class which is used for capturing the video of the iphone screen available on net] which simply  record the screen and save the **.mp4** file to the document directory. My problem is that I performing the animation on the screen with the animation property of the `UIImageView`, but in the video the animation is not shown. It simply shows the single image in the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello friends i got the answer of my problem i m posting this so you don't get worried as i did!!!
Just simply change the 
 [[self.layer presentationLayer] renderInContext:context]
 in drawRect() instead of
 [self.layer renderInContext:context] in file ScreenCaptureView.m

and it will start working ,thanks....you can also see this [link](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) for more